# Long list creating sorted() TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, stock

`option_list` is a list of dictionaries with strings.

This code works as long as the `option_list` list is not too large.

```
option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: option['expiration_date'])
option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: option['strike_price'], reverse=True)
```

It's sorting the option data by expiration date and strike price.

However, when the `option_list` list gets to an arbitrary-to-me length, it throws this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-237-7fd70ddaa35a> in <module>()
      3 # option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: (option['expiration_date'], option['strike_price']))
      4 
----> 5 option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: option['expiration_date'])
      6 option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: option['strike_price'], reverse=True)
      7 

<ipython-input-237-7fd70ddaa35a> in <lambda>(i)
      3 # option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: (option['expiration_date'], option['strike_price']))
      4 
----> 5 option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: option['expiration_date'])
      6 option_list = sorted(option_list, key = lambda option: option['strike_price'], reverse=True)
      7 

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

However, truncating the `option_list` list to an arbitrary number works again:

```
option_list = sorted(option_list[:-5000], key = lambda option: option['expiration_date'])
```

I've tried `-1000`, but that is not low enough.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it so I don't have to cut off data?

Comment: I think the problem is not caused by a list that is too long. I think that the error is caused by a missing (None/NaN) value.

Comment: Do you think that it might be relevant to the data itself? Could it be that some part of the data is couropted?

Comment: What is `print(option_list.index(None))` saying?

Comment: @MustafaAydın - Returns 13765. Indexing to `option_list[13765]` returns None. How can I filter them out?

Comment: `[opt for opt in option_list if opt is not None]`

Comment: Or use something like `key = lambda option: option['expiration_date'] if option is not None else “”`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your problem is missing data. Since the error is referencing to NoneTypes.
Try filtering the missing data out first:

```
no_missing_options = [o for o in option_list if o]
option_list = sorted(no_missing_options , key=lambda x: x['expiration_date'])
```

Comment: This will exclude many other possible `o` values besides `None`; essentially those that evaluate to `False` in boolean context, e.g., 0.

Comment: Use test `if o is not None` Instead of `if o`

Comment: In this case it does not matter, since OP expects dictionaries in the list

Comment: Yes but it turned out there was `None`(s) in the list after all...

Comment: True, so any other values than dictionaries are unwanted in this case

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the variable name. I believe it should not match what you are sorting. I also think Mustafa Aydin is correct. But, maybe just add an 's' on the end of the variable making it option_lists and it will work.